# Adobe AIR- connection issues with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, apache-flex, air, socket.io

I have a desktop app in Adobe Air (flex). 
I have used [flashSocket.io](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) library in my app to communicate with socket.io on node.js server.

It works perfectly for most of the clients.
But for some random client the flex app is not able to create a connection with the socket.io server. It constantly throws connection error and close error on flex. The clients are not behind any firewalls or proxy server.

The console has warning like

```
Web Socket Connection Invalid
```

I guess this for those clients who are not able to connect.

Since its working for majority of the users i don't know where should i look into. Also, i am unable to reproduce this on my side.

Here's the Server Code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', app.name, app.url);
});
io.configure(function() {
  io.set('transports', ['flashsocket']);
  io.set('flash policy port', 843);
});
```

Flex code:

```
socket = new FlashSocket("http://domain.com:8080/");
socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.CONNECT, onConnect);
socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.MESSAGE, onMessage);
socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.CLOSE, onDisconnect); //only close and connect_error event is always fired for certain clients
socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different port, we're using 443.